# How do I get the remaining daily mail quota of google apps scripts service to work consistently?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I did a project on google apps scripts to send automatic emails after a form response was sent. However, when I check the daily quota of remaining emails with the `MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()` method, the quota responses vary with each script execution.

So I created another project just to test the quota, using the `MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()` method and even so, the quota response varied with each execution.

---

Code used to test:

```
function testeDeCota() { 
  let cota;

  cota = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  Logger.log("Cota de emails restantes: " + cota);

  cota = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  Logger.log("Cota de emails restantes: " + cota);

}
```

I am using a workspace account that has a quota of 1500 emails/day.

This is a screeshot of my executions. Note that there are 3 consecutive executions and without sending any email, even so the quota responses varied. The responses were:

> 1394;
> 1399;
> 1390.

Whenever I try to send an email or get the quota information the number just varies randomly.

[printscreen of the script executions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfVU2.png)

Comment: I can confirmed that getReamingDailyQuota() method consistently returns 1500 so I don't the same problem as you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### This seems to be intended behavior.

Apart from the older issue Marios mentioned ([Gmail SendEmail Quota - Decrementing Bug/issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36764211)), this was reported recently in Issue Tracker, and closed as `Intended Behaviour`:

- [MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() is giving incorrect information](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176999830)

See comments [#6](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176999830#comment6) and [#8](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176999830#comment8):

> This small fluctuation in the value returned by this method is to be expected.

> This behaviour is caused by how quotas are internally handled by Apps Script. It's expected behaviour.

#### Different executions vs Loop:

Interestingly, this discrepancy can only be seen when calling this method in separate invocations. When calling this method in a loop instead, no fluctuation is shown:

```
for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(documentID).getSheetByName(sheetName).appendRow([new Date(), MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()]);
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
}
```

#### File a feature request:

As suggested in the referenced issue, if this is impacting your workflow somehow, you could consider [filing a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113).